# JSON Data String Replacement and Date Formatting

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I am fairly new to JSON & JavaScript so I apologise if it seems I haven't done enough research. With reference to the following link:

http://jsbin.com/imekip/edit#javascript,live

I would like to know how to amend the code from:

> Our next gig is at The Fillmore, San Francisco, CA, US on 2012-04-18

To:

> Our next gig is at The Fillmore, San Francisco on 4th May

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You should add some code, otherwise it appears you just have to change a string from A to B.

Comment: Hi Felix Kling, sorry if the link wasn't ok, I thought that might have been easier. The part of that link I am trying to replace is '<li>Our next gig is at <a href='{uri}'>{venue.displayName}, {location.city} on {start.date}</a></li>", item));'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it takes a little of code to do
1) in the each loop you have to store the date variable and assign the name of each month to the number of the month using the date object
2) Also check to convert the day to a string using some string function
3) Least but not last, the location must be cut till the first comma appears, I have used the split function since you may use the rest of the string in further situations
Full working demo here
http://jsfiddle.net/theodore/WrCLW/2/

Comment: Hi Theodore. Thanks for the Demo, it's really helpful. Would it be possible for you to do another jsfiddle using an external data source? eg http://www.lofiz.co.uk/afba/songkickwidget/testjsondata.json Thank you!

Comment: Your Json result has an error, 
Parse error on line 1:
?({    "resultsPage
^
Expecting '{', '['

If you make it valid JSON it is quite simple  to use it with $getJSON 
function http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I corrected the JSON, that link should now be fine. I've been messing around with the getJSON but I can't seem to get to work. Sorry to be a pain but I would be so grateful if you could take another look at your demo for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<ul id="ulId">
    <li>Our next gig is at 
        <a href='#'>
            The Fillmore, San Francisco, CA, US on 2012-05-18
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>Our next gig is at 
        <a href='#'>
            The Fillmore, San Francisco, CA, US on 2012-10-15
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

​

**JS**

```
var months=['January','February','March','April','May', 'June', 'July', 'August','September','October','November','December'];
var rgx = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/;
function changeDate(ul)
{
    for(i=0;i<ul.childNodes.length;i++)
    {
        if(ul.childNodes[i].tagName=="LI")
        {
            var link=ul.childNodes[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
            var txt=link.innerHTML;
            var r = txt.match(rgx);
            var dateArr=r[0].split('-');
            var m= parseInt(dateArr[1])-1;
            var d=dateArr[2];
            var dt= d+'th '+months[m];
            var final=txt.replace(r[0] ,dt);  
            link.innerHTML=final;
        }
    }
}
changeDate('ulId'); // call the function and pass the ul id as paremeter.
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ngRXZ/5/)